# Deploy a nextjs app to vercel and point subdomain from cloudflare

Tags: next.js, cloudflare, vercel

I need to deploy a nextjs app to vercel and I am using cloudflare to manage the dns. I need to point dev.domain.com to vercel deployment. In vercel `Project Settings-> Domains` I have added the sub domain.
In cloudflare I have added the records as type: cname . name: dev content: cname.vercel-dns.com . In vercel it is showing valid configuration. When I tried to access the subdomain it says site cant be reached with error code as `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add A record for your subdomain pointing to vercel ip.

```
Type: A
Name: dev
Content: vercel ip
```

make sure to switch off proxy status until vercel verifies your site